# Views - Contextual filter -  "page not found"

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that uses a contextual filters of type

> Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

The page display has the following path `/objects/%`
If I access the site through http://mysite.com/objects/all the view gets triggered and all my objects are listed, http://mysite.com/objects/silver also works fine (now only objects tagged with silver are listed), but if I use http://mysite.com/objects then I get a `"Page not found"` message, how can I solve this? I wan't the `/objects` and `/objects/all` to show exactly the same content.
Of course I could copy the display and add a path for `/objects` but that don't seem quite right.

Comment: As I just discovered from another answered question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869512/drupal-7-views-with-2-contextual-filters-not-working-if-second-filter-not-define), the solution is not to specify a path argument as that would make it required and also set an expected path as is mentioned by Letharion. In other words, just set the path as "objects".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an unfortunate side effect of how the menu system works. When the paramter "%" isn't available, you match against a different path, and the View won't get called.

I suggest making /objects an alias to /objects/all, I believe this will then interact properly with the menu-system.
If that's not the case, you can force the issue with [Path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) which will redirect the user with an HTTP-response code, and thus land the user at /objects/all.

I minor drawback of using Path redirect is that the redirect logically belongs together with the View, but is now configured somewhere completely different. For that reason, I would prefer to accomplish the redirect and View rendering with Page manager, which will allow you to group the HTTP-response and a Panel together in a more logical manner.

Comment: Thank you. Creating an alias like "objects" for "objects/all" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the contextual menu there are a set of options under *When the filter value is NOT in the URL*. Select *Provide a default value* and type `all`

Comment: Already tried that without success, it seems like the view isn't loaded at all when i goto `/objects/`

Comment: Will it work when you try /objects/all then ?

Comment: Yes, it does, just seems like it won't supply the default arguments if they are missing.